# Using LTSPice to make Function Blocks for SIMULINK

Tags: ltspice, matlab, pll, simulink

I have a PLL that I want to model in Simulink using the control theory toolkit. I have the schematics for the PLL in LTSpice. Does anyone know of a way that I can integrate the spice model with my MATLAB simulation? I'd like to to turn the individual parts of the circuit into Simulink functional blocks (based on the SPICE netlists)

Comment: If you're expecting a "click-and-go" approach, forget it. You have to break your schematics into pieces and rebuild it in Simulink. It shouldn't be too hard, after all, you did manage to build the schematic in LTspice, no?

Comment: ok, so basically just put it into Simscape? Because I have that toolbox. Or is there away to import a netlist (LTSpice) into Simscape?